# Mongo Scala Async Client not writing

Tags: mongodb, scala, asynchronous, mongodb-query

trying to upsert with the new Scala Async Driver using this code, but the DB never gets created even though this is called many times:

```
override def insertOrUpdateOne(user: UserNew): Future[Unit] = {
  users.replaceOne(equal("_id", user._id), user)
    .toFuture
    .map(_ => ())
}
```

mongo client created fine, collection created fine, but the above causes no write to be performed in fact the db is never created (which should happen on the first write). I have other code that uses casbah and that is working synchronously.

`users` is the Mongo collection with no syntactic sugar from me. (edited)

`toFuture` seems to do the subscribe (which should trigger the write?) but it still doesn't work. I'm mixing some collections with casbah and one with the async client, the casbah ones work but not the one above using async.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is your `insertOrUpdateOne` method being called? A future will begin running asynchronously in a separate thread when it is created. Are you waiting for the future to complete before attempting to access the new record?

Comment: I do not wait for the `Future` I create it and go. Nothing needs to be done after the `insertOrUpdate` I do not need synchronous consistency. When I `findOne` I process it in a `.map` to deal with the actual retrieved data when it comes back, so I process it asynchronously too. This seems ok except the write is never triggered and since I'm not directly using the Observable and subscription (should be handled by `toFuture` afaik) I wonder what will trigger the write. When I `replaceOne` I expect it to happen even if I don't need to wait for it.

Comment: Ah but @Chris C if you are asking how I know the write never happens, I use the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
override def insertOrUpdateOne(user: UserNew): Future[Unit] = {
  users.replaceOne(equal("_id", user._id), user, UpdateOptions().upsert(true))
    .toFuture
    .map(_ => ())
}
```

Nothing in the docs but when I read the code I see it defaults upsert to false.

BTW this allows us to ignore all the `Observable` and `subscribe` stuff and setup of callbacks. Just process the results in a Scala idiomatic `someFuture.map()` This makes the `UsersDao`non-Mongo specific code as an interface. This in turn allows all code in the `UsersDaoImpl`to handle Mongo specific stuff, which enables the `Impl` to be injected so a runtime choice can be made about which `Impl` to use. Mongo can be replaced without dependent code caring or knowing about the `Impl`.